# JS: удалить атрибуты нескольких тегов циклом

Tags: javascript

Несколько изображений содержит атрибут class, который подставляется CMS.

```
<img alt="" class="..." style="..." src="/image.jpg">
<img alt="" class="..." style="..." src="/image.jpg">
<img alt="" class="..." style="..." src="/image.jpg">
<img alt="" class="..." style="..." src="/image.jpg">
<img alt="" class="..." style="..." src="/image.jpg">
```

изображения добавляются и убираются динамически. Подскажите способ обхода циклом изображений по очереди и удаления атрибутов `class="..."` и `style="..."`

Comment: Не дубликат, просто схожие темы.

Comment: В дубликате: "Изображение содержит атрибут class, который подставляется CMS. Подскажите способ удаления атрибута class". Текущий вопрос: "Несколько изображений содержит атрибут class, который подставляется CMS. Подскажите способ обхода циклом изображений по очереди и удаления атрибутов class". Вообще ни разу не дубль. Но теперь нужно удалить атрибут не с одного элемента, а с множества. Если нужно будет удалить еще один атрибут с этих элементов, создадите новый вопрос?

Comment: Буду стараться укладывать все вопросы в одну тему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если на JavaScript.
Ищем контейнер в котором находятся изображения и удаляем атрибуты.

```
var container = document.getElementById('content'),
    elements = container.getElementsByTagName('img');
[].forEach.call(elements, function( el ) {
    el.removeAttribute('class');
    el.removeAttribute('style');
});
```

Comment: То, что надо. Благодарю!